# Getting Strings which are multiple lines

Tags: c++, string

Here i have a string which is split and each line is in a different cell in a vector and i want to retrieve all of the line if the first three letters are **.N/** however it seems that i can only retrieve one of the lines which start with **.N/** below is the string which i am working with.

```
std::string message = ".N/1TLIS/PART/123456789I/A/1234RFGH67323\n"
    ".N/AT0931/2DEC/GVA/Y\n"
    ".I/KL0967/02APR/AMS/F\n"
    ".O/123/MARRIOTT/27MAY/084512L//FEDEXVAN45\n";
```

**CODE WHICH I USE AT THE MOMENT**

```
std::vector<std::string> el; //VECTOR
    split(el,message,boost::is_any_of("\n"));// the string above is split line for line into vector el

 for(int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++)
     {
         if(el[i].substr(0,3) == ".N/")
         {

             str = el[i].substr(3);

         }
     }
     cout << str;
```

However when i print out **str** i only get **"1TLIS/PART/123456789I/A/1234RFGH67323"**
and not **1TLIS/PART/123456789I/A/1234RFGH67323 and "AT0931/2DEC/GVA/Y"**

Is there a way where i can retrieve all lines starting which a specific character?

Comment: Show us how you initialize `el`.

Comment: could you post the code related to `el`?

Comment: @nabulke code has bee n edited in the question

Comment: @shengy code has been edited in the question

Comment: `str` will be overwritten in every loop. Try `str +=` instead? `cout` is used intentionally **after** the loop?

Comment: @nabulke yes `cout` is being used intentionally **after** the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append to str, currently you are just replacing, try:
First initialize str with "" before the for loop, then inside the for loop

```
str.append(el[i].substr(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative solution using algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;

ostream_iterator<string> out_it(cout, "\n");

remove_copy_if(el.begin(), el.end(), out_it, 
    !boost::bind(boost::algorithm::starts_with<string, string>, _1, ".N/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++)
{
    if(el[i].substr(0,3) == ".N/")
    {

        str = el[i].substr(3);
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}
```

`str` is overwritten at every time you found `".N/"`, and you just outputed the last one.